# mac-screen-capture-permissions module make failed at Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: npm, electron, macos-catalina, jitsi

I want to run jitsi meet electron project from github. So I tried npm install in my project directory to install necessary node module packages. During that time the following error occured.

error: implicit declaration of function 'CGPreflightScreenCaptureAccess' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
hasPermissions = CGPreflightScreenCaptureAccess();

in package.json file :
"mac-screen-capture-permissions": "^1.1.0"

full error:

```
> mac-screen-capture-permissions@1.1.0 install /Users/apple01/Documents/Boithok/jitsi-meet-electron-master/node_modules/mac-screen-capture-permissions
> prebuild-install || node install.js

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=14.16.1 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=darwin)

> mac-screen-capture-permissions@1.1.0 native_build /Users/apple01/Documents/Boithok/jitsi-meet-electron-master/node_modules/mac-screen-capture-permissions
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/screencapturepermissions/screen-capture-permissions.o
../screen-capture-permissions.m:12:22: error: implicit declaration of function 'CGPreflightScreenCaptureAccess' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    hasPermissions = CGPreflightScreenCaptureAccess();
                     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/screencapturepermissions/screen-capture-permissions.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/Cellar/node@14/14.16.1_1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node@14/14.16.1_1/bin/node" "/usr/local/Cellar/node@14/14.16.1_1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/apple01/Documents/Boithok/jitsi-meet-electron-master/node_modules/mac-screen-capture-permissions
gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mac-screen-capture-permissions@1.1.0 native_build: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mac-screen-capture-permissions@1.1.0 native_build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple01/.npm/_logs/2021-05-04T05_46_57_224Z-debug.log

> robotjs@0.6.0 install /Users/apple01/Documents/Boithok/jitsi-meet-electron-master/node_modules/robotjs
> prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=14.16.1 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=darwin)
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/robotjs.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/deadbeef_rand.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/mouse.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/keypress.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/keycode.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/screen.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/screengrab.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/snprintf.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/MMBitmap.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/robotjs.node
```

Answer (score 0):

The module won't compile on macOS 10.15.7 because it `CGPreflightScreenCaptureAccess` isn't available on that version. At runtime, the module checks the macOS version before calling that API so it won't crash.

> Building the module from source requires macOS 11+ SDK, but the resulting module will still run on <10.15, 10.15 and 11+.